# Counter not increasing more than one time

Tags: php

I wanted to make specific letter counter, but my counter is not increasing more that once. Can some one explain what i'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

**PHP:**

```
<?php 

$count_s = 0; 
$count_v = 0;
$input = '';

if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $input = $_POST['inp'];
        switch($input) {

            case 'v':
                $count_v++;

            case 's':
                $count_s++;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Enter Symbol: </h3>

<form action="index.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" class="input" name='inp' maxlength="1" >
    <button class="btn" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form> 

<div class="output">
    <?php 
        echo "Count of letter 'V': ".$count_v."<br/>"; 
        echo "Count of letter 'S': ".$count_s."<br/>"; 
    ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The counts don't persist between form sends. It's reset every time the code is loaded. You need to save the count to file/a database.

Comment: @Carcigenicate but it can save to input value is i put like this <input type="hidden value="<?PHP echo $count_v; ?>">

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But `count_s` is reinitialized to zero every time `$count_s = 0;` is run, which is everytime the page loads.

Comment: Andrew, yes you can use hidden fields to store the counters status, but you have to read them ex, `$_POST['hidden_count_s']` and init the `$counter` with the value, not with `0`

Comment: your cases are missing breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will be work perfectly. paste it in any test file. This will retain no of times you input `v` and no of times you input `s`, value of `s` and `v` will remain same of input some other value.

```
<?php
$input = '';
if(!isset($count_v))
{
    $count_v=0;
}
if(!isset($count_s))
{
    $count_s=0;
}
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit'))
{

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $input = $_POST['inp'];
        switch ($input)
        {

            case 'v':
                $_POST['count_v']++;
                $count_v=$_POST['count_v'];
                $count_s=$_POST['count_s'];
                break;

            case 's':
                $count_v=$_POST['count_v'];
                $_POST['count_s']++;
                $count_s=$_POST['count_s'];
                break;
            default:
                $count_v=$_POST['count_v'];
                $count_s=$_POST['count_s'];
                break;
        }
    }
}
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Enter Symbol: </h3>

        <form method="POST"> 
            <input type="hidden" name='count_v' value="<?php echo $count_v?>">
            <input type="hidden" name='count_s' value="<?php echo $count_s?>">
            <input type="text" class="input" name='inp' maxlength="1" >
            <button class="btn" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form> 

        <div class="output">
            <?php
            echo "Count of letter 'V': " . $count_v . "<br/>";
            echo "Count of letter 'S': " . $count_s . "<br/>";
            ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I have updated my post, At that moment i haven't enabled `ini_set("display_errors", 1);`, thanks for reminding... +1 for you

Comment: NP. I just prefer having validation also for empty variables, since you never know exactly what type of error-settings other users have. You only have control over your own server, depending on the needs of other users (if it's a public script) you might need to make sure. Also, it's just good practice to never have any notices, warnings or errors at all :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to store counters in each request, because the variables lifetime is short (request life time), then they will be re-init from 0

to do this you can store the counters in file, database, or session
it depends on the time you want them to persist.

below is a sample for using session

** note the new line `session_start();` you need to add it.

```
<?php 
session_start();

$count_s = 0; 
$count_v = 0;
$input = '';

if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $input = $_POST['inp'];
        switch($input) {

            case 'v':
                if(!isset($_SESSION["count_v"])){
                    $_SESSION["count_v"] = 0;
                }
                $tmp = $_SESSION["count_v"];
                $tmp++;
                $_SESSION["count_v"] = $tmp;
            break;
            case 's':
                if(!isset($_SESSION["count_s"])){
                    $_SESSION["count_s"] = 0;
                }
                $tmp = $_SESSION["count_s"];
                $tmp++;
                $_SESSION["count_s"] = $tmp;
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

and to read the values (in html page) use this:

```
<?php 
      echo "Count of letter 'V': ".$_SESSION["count_v"]."<br/>"; 
      echo "Count of letter 'S': ".$_SESSION["count_s"]."<br/>"; 
?>
```

if you are going to store more than the 2 letters (s and v) then you can make the session key "count_v" generated dynamically using input itself. this will be a much less code, you will not need a `switch/case`

**Edit:** as i saw in your comment above, yes you can maintain counter values using hidden fields in HTML page, and use them to initialize the `$count_s` and `$count_v` instead of zero. you need to take care of first request when hidden values might be unset, or they could be zero

Comment: just as the OP did; missing breaks for cases

Comment: opps. @Fred-ii- i actually copied the OP's code lol, i will fix it :) Thanks